# Why does my Windows XP mouse cursor jumps around?

Tags: windows-xp, mouse

I have Windows XP SP3 on a Dell Latitude D610. The problem is that my mouse cursor jumps around the screen when I move it or click. I tried to reinstall it, but again that problem occurs. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Are you referring to the built-in mouse? Or an external one? Or does it happen with all mice?

Comment: I use built-in one. I didn't have use external one. But that built-in was good before.

Comment: Well, hardware sometimes fails. First thing to do now is try another mouse with the internal one disabled.

Comment: @gronostaj: Thank you. Is there any softwaring way to solve the problem as a second thing? My mean is that, is there any code, statement or so on on Windows to dose that?

Comment: If it's in fact a faulty hardware, then no - your internal mouse just sends invalid movement information and there's no way to distinguish it from real movement.

Comment: @gronostaj: Fortunately it was not a faculty hardware and I solve the problem by downloading suitable driver from DELL site. Thank you very much